# Arithmetical formalization of "F is sound"

Tags: logic, computability

In [How subtle is Gödel's theorem? More on Roger Penrose](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/behavioral-and-brain-sciences/article/how-subtle-is-godels-theorem-more-on-roger-penrose/BAB3BE6BB16788CB19C0A6479F2C72AA), Martin Davis points out the fact that the statement

> **F** is sound $\implies$ G(**F**) is true

where F is some recursively axiomizable extension of **Q** and G(**F**) is the Gödel sentence of **F**, is a $\Delta^0_2$ sentence. I am wondering if someone can show me or direct me to a reference where this is explicitly shown. I spent a long time trying to formalize it but I could not come up with a way to express "**F** is sound" arithmetically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the fine print here, you’ll see that by “sound”, Davis means $\Pi_1$-sound. There is a arithmetical truth predicate for $\Pi_1$ sentences (in fact, this predicate is $\Pi_1$) so the statement is just “if every $\Pi_1$ sentence in $F$ is true, then $G(F)$ is true.” Where by “is true” we mean “satisfies the truth predicate for $\Pi_1$ sentences”.

As for why it is $\Delta_2$, since the property of being in $F$ is $\Sigma_1$ and truth is $\Pi_1$, “F is sound” is of the form $\forall x(\Sigma_1\to\Pi_1)$ and since $\Sigma_1\to\Pi_1$ is $\Pi_1,$ the whole thing is $\Pi_1.$ Since truth is $\Pi_1,$ “$G(F)$ is true” is $\Pi_1.$ So the whole assertion has the form $\Pi_1\to\Pi_1,$ which is $\Delta_2.$

Comment: Right, I don't know why I didn't realize what I was asking was just whether or not arithmetical truth was arithmetically definable, of course it isn't. Specifically, what I'm wondering about is your second paragraph. I don't know why $\Sigma_1\to\Pi_1$ is $\Pi_1,$ or why $\Pi_1\to\Pi_1$ is $\Delta_2$. The explanations of the arithmetical hierarchy that I've seen haven't explained why those identities are the case, or if they did I didn't follow. It's fine if you don't want to give a full proof of those but could you give me a reference?

Comment: @Dkn557 First, $\Sigma_n$ and $\Pi_n$ are closed under conjunction / disjunction. The easiest way to see this is probably to remember how to put a formula into prenex normal form. Then since $A\to B$ is $\lnot A\lor B,$ $\Sigma_1\to\Pi_n$ is $\Pi_1\lor \Pi_1,$ which by closure is $\Pi_1.$ $\Pi_1\to\Pi_1$ is $\Sigma_1\lor \Pi_1.$ Here the best we can do is realize a $\Pi_1$ and a $\Sigma_1$ are both $\Delta_2$ so by closure the disjunction is $\Delta_2.$

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, full soundness (which is *not* what Martin is talking about, per spaceisdarkgreen's answer) **is not arithmetically expressible**. Precisely:

> There is no formula $\varphi$ in the language of arithmetic such that whenever $T$ is a (index for a) recursively enumerable theory in the language of arithmetic, $T$ is sound iff $\varphi(T)$ is true (in the standard model $\mathbb{N}$).

*(We need to bring different $T$s into the picture to avoid triviality; e.g. since PA is actually sound, technically the sentence "$2+2=4$" is equivalent to the soundness of PA.)*

This is just Tarski's undefinability theorem all over again: letting $e_\psi$ be the canonical index for the r.e. theory $\{\psi\}$ we have that $\psi$ is true iff $\varphi(e_\psi)$ is true, and this gives us a way to define truth in the language of arithmetic.